# CognosTM1 Error: Syntax Error on or before Value

Tags: business-intelligence, cognos, cognos-10, cognos-8, cognos-tm1

I am trying to insert a Numeric value( mesure ) to database from Tm1 cube.
The variable 'Value' type in tm1 is a Numeric, and the 'Value' type in Database is decimal.

I tried to do a check if the variable contains string values , so I put them in a sperated file. And if they are Numeric I insert them in the database.

But it seems that there is an error in my sql query which states :

```
Syntax Error on or before Value
```

I dont know why it gives me an error even I checked o it and verified if it is Numeric.

Here is a snippet of my code :

```
 zType = DTYPE( 'Sales', Sales );

    IF(zType @= 'N');

    SQL_INSERT_N2 = 'INSERT INTO DB VALUES ( '''| dim1|''' ,  '''| dim2|''',  '''|Value|''') ' ; #error in this line

 ELSE;

 zValue =NumberToString( Value ) ;

 zText = dim1 | ';' | dim2 | ';' | Value | ; 

 ASCIIOUTPUT( zFile, zText );

ENDIF;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was declaring a numeric value as a string value by adding `'''|Value|'''`.

So it should be something like this :

```
SQL= 'INSERT INTO DB VALUES ( '''| dim1|''' ,  '''| dim2|''',  '|NumberToString(Value)|') ' ;
```